# How to pre-select a value in RadioButtonList inside a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

This might be a silly question but how can I preselect a `RadioButtonList` value based on existing data?

I have this code inside the aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="ItemCommand" >
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbLevel" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Read" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Edit" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But I can't set the value of the list. `RadioButtonList` doesn't have a `SelectedValue` property, setting `DataValueField` has no effect and I can't set the values one by one (using something like:  `Selected='<%# ((Rights)Container.DataItem).Level == 1  %>'`) because databinding happens on the list not specific items.

Comment: You can use Gridview_RowDatabound event for pre-select the value based on datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the GridView's `RowDataBound()` method to set the RadioButton list accordingly:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {               
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbLevel");
            // Query the DataSource & get the corresponding data....
            // ...
            // if Read -> then Select 0 else if Edit then Select 1...
            rbLevel.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

U can use

`rbLevel.SelectedIndex = 1;`

OR

can assign id for each radio button and then use

`rbLevel.FindControl("option2").Selected = true;`

Hope this will work :)

Answer (score 2):

try with `ListItem` selected property as below

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbLevel" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Read" Value="0" Selected ="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Edit" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

OR

form code behind you can set by the selected Index property

```
rbLevel.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

if the selected item depend on data source, after data binding you can find the item and set the selection as below form the code behind.

```
rbLevel.Items.FindByValue(searchText).Selected = true;
```

Comment: I need to pre-select values based on data I have in my datasource (some rows it'll be 0 some will be 1).

Comment: is it first item you need to select?

Comment: not always, as I said in the question it depends on the data I get from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the best answer i have found

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButtonList rbl = gvRow.FindControl("rblPromptType") as RadioButtonList;
        HiddenField hf = gvRow.FindControl("hidPromptType") as HiddenField;

        if (rbl != null && hf != null)
        {
            if (hf.Value != "")
            {
                //clear the default selection if there is one
                rbl.ClearSelection();
            }

            rbl.SelectedValue = hf.Value;
        }
    }
}
```